# Speed up OpenUri by keeping connection open?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to speed up OpenUri connections in Ruby, maybe by somehow keeping the stream open?

Here is what I'm currently doing to retrieve data:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML( open(url).read )
```

which seems to be slow when batch processing several thousand URLs.

Answer (score 2):

If you're processing several thousand URLs using OpenURI, you're using the wrong library. Instead you should be looking at something that will let you process them in parallel.

I recommend you look at using [Typhoeus and Hydra](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus). Typhoeus is the the code that gets the URL, and Hydra handles the multiple connections. Check out the examples on the main page to see how easy it is to have many parallel connections running at once.

Run some benchmark tests to determine at what point you saturate your host, and your internet connection. Trying to run more connections than your pipe can handle just wastes CPU time. Also, be careful if you're trying to process multiple connections to the same host as you're eating up their bandwidth and CPU too, which is a great way to get banned.

Answer (score 0):

Try `net-http-persistent` ([rubygems](http://rubygems.org/gems/net-http-persistent), [github](https://github.com/drbrain/net-http-persistent)).